# Visual studio setup project: default installation location based on user choce

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, setup-project

Is it possible to change the DefaultLocation proprty based on a user choice on a visual stuio 2013 setup project?
I have inserted a radio button dialog in User interface but I don't know how to use the selected button property to change the DefaultLocation propetry, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There already is a usr choice to specify the output directory. The user interface sequence has an InstallFolder dialog where you specify the Application Folder (as it's called in the File System view). That's the way the user browses to a location that is not the default of [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName] .

If you want to change the default location and base it on a search then this should work, assuming you have a registry entry defining the location:

1. Create a custom folder in the file system view, and give it a default location that's the same as the Application Folder setting, and an uppercase Property there called (for example) MYPATH. Put your files there, not Application Folder.
2. Add a registry search, in Search Target machine in launch conditions, and refer to the key and registry location, and with the Property MYPATH.
3. At install time the search will set the path to the value in the registry and install the files there.

The problem is that Visual Studio setup projects don't offer all the capabilities of Windows Installer, although other tools do. With other tools you could run code to set the location, just as an example.

Comment: Thanks, but i'd like the default directory could be changed automatically due to a previous (binary) user choice. This to relieve the user to specify exactly the desidered directory.

Comment: There is nothing in a Visual Studio setup that automatically changes the default directory on an upgrade unless you added something. An upgrade is the same as a fresh install that happens to uninstall the previous version if there is one there. You may need to rephrase the question. Also, why do you need a RadioButton? They are nothing to do with directories.

Comment: I'd like to create an installer that has different default installation directory based on run time user choice during installation.

Comment: My sw works on a PC and on an industrial panel controller. For the installation on a PC the defalult "program files" directory is ok, but on the industrial panel the destination directory is forced and complex to find / type. It would be useful that a choiche during installation presets the (default?) installation directory.